# Exchange 2010 - All maiboxes with auditing enabled

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to return a list of all mailboxes that have auditing enabled. I have tried the below, but it is returning all the users and not just those that have auditing enabled on their mailboxes. Can someone please help. Thanks

Get-Mailbox | select Name | where-object {$_.AuditEnabled -eq $true}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want check your pipeline and move the where-object before the select eg

get-mailbox | Where-Object {$_.AuditEnabled -eq $true} | select Name

Cheers
Glen